# AWS Glue DynamicFrame tries to write empty string as null

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I have a AWS Glue Job moving data from RDS table to Redshift.

both table has same schema:

```
-- RDS
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   id varchar(256) not null primary key
   col1 varchar(256) not null
) 

-- Redshift
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   id varchar(256) not null 
   col1 varchar(256) not null
) sortkey(id)
```

I crawled both schemas and wrote a trivial job to write `DynamicFrame` from RDS source to Redshift sink.

```
val datasource = glueContext.getCatalogSource(
      database = "my_rds",
      tableName = "my_table",
      redshiftTmpDir = ""
    ).getDynamicFrame()

glueContext.getCatalogSink(
      database = "my_redshift",
      tableName = "my_table",
      redshiftTmpDir = "s3://some-bucket/some-path"
    ).writeDynamicFrame(datasource)
```

but the job fails for rows with empty string values of `col1` with:

```
java.sql.SQLException:
Error (code 1213) while loading data into Redshift: "Missing data for not-null field"
Table name: my_table
Column name: col1
Column type: varchar(254)
Raw line: 3027616797,@NULL@
Raw field value: @NULL@
```

When I debug this with a `glue-spark-shell` I can verify that the value is an empty string `""`.

```
scala> datasource.toDF().filter("id = '3027616797'").select("col1").collect().head.getString(0)
res23: String = ""
```

How can I tell glue to distinguish between empty strings `""` and `NULL`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem in [Databricks Datasource for Redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-redshift.html)) (apparently AWS Glue uses it internally). There are open tickets regarding exactly this problem but they have not been touched for over a year:

- https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/331
- https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/49

I have tried that code, but the result is exactly the same:

```
datasource
  .toDF()
  .write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
  .option("url", "<RS_JDBC_URL>?user=<USER>&password=<PASSWORD>")
  .option("dbtable", "my_table")
  .option("tempdir", "s3://S_PATH")
  .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true")
  .save
```